# My legacy G-Suite email address stopped receiving all email

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, smtp

I set up a G Suite account for an organization's domain that I owned back when that was a free service. I'm effectively grandfathered in now for life; now Google refers to it as a "legacy G Suite account." For all intents and purposes it's just a regular G Suite account; I just don't get billed for it but I also get no support from Google.

Recently I noticed that my email address was no longer getting any emails. If I log into that account and send a message to myself, that is the only thing that works. Trying to email in from any other account at all results in a bounce back with this message:

```
530 SMTP authentication is required.
```

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this, frankly. This email address has worked for the longest time and this is only a recent result. I definitely haven't been fiddling with any settings so I'm not sure what change occurred on Google's end that would have brought this about. Any ideas on how to fix this, so I can start receiving email again?

Comment: Please read [SMTP error reference](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén that reference is not helpful. It redirects to a troubleshooting article titled "I can't sign into my email client." But that is not the problem. I can sign in just fine. The problem is that my account is not receiving email. That 530 error message is what gets sent in the bounce back from "Mail Delivery Subsystem" to the sender.

Comment: How do you go that article? The error 530  Authentication Required points to "Use IMAP to check Gmail on other email clients". Anyway to check that your G Suite email and DNS are OK try https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/main/

Comment: The link goes to the #cantsignin anchor on that page which is titled "I can't sign into my email client." I see that if you scroll all the way to the top the title is actually "Use IMAP to check Gmail on other email clients." But either way it misses the mark... I can clearly see the bounceback messages being delivered to every other address that tries to send to this account. Whether I check it directly in the browser or with Outlook/Thunderbird/etc doesn't change that. I am looking into the DNS records however... I did have to migrate the site's "A" records recently.

Comment: Checkout this [Restrict messages to authorized addresses or domains](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2640542?hl=en) and [Not receiving any email in G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9122043?hl=en&ref_topic=1354754)

Comment: The bounty came before the answer. Now that I have it figured out I'm not sure how to cancel the bounty

Comment: It's not possible to cancel a bounty. Ref. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/bounty (P.D. just in "very rare" cases a bounty could be cancelled like when a bounty is offered to prevent the closing of a very bad question; I'm not sure if a diamond moderador could do this directly )

Comment: Well in that case if either of you want the bounty, go ahead and post an answer. Otherwise it will just go to waste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the DNS records. Recently I had to migrate my hosting provider for the domain, I thought I was just updating "A" records but apparently all the MX records vanished along with DKIM entries, SPF, etc. I ran [this tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/check) to find out what was missing. Then I had to wait 12 hours or so for things to propagate, but now it seems to be working again.

Answer (score 1):

The G Suite Administrator Help Center include a lot of information that could help us to troubleshoot many problems, specially those related to the email service.

In cases like this, **delivery problems after changing DNS records**, the help article that could be the best reference is [Troubleshoot MX records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/140038). It includes instructions for the following steps, among other things:

1. Step 1: waiting 72 hours after making DNS records changes,
2. Step 2: Check the DNS records

   - Check the MX records that are applied to your primary domain
   - Check your MX records using an MX lookup tool
   - Check your DNS configuration with the Check MX tool
3. Step 3: Add or remove the @ sign